# CardHeader is not rendering in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm playing with React and material-ui, other stuff have worked but for some reason `<CardHeader>` is not getting rendered.
Below is the code

```js
import React from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import Typography from "material-ui/Typography";

class PaperCard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardHeader title="CaHellord" subheader="Test ME" />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography type="title">Word of the day</Typography>
          <Typography type="headline" component="h2">
            impediments
          </Typography>
          <Typography component="p">adjective</Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions>
          <Button dense> Learn More </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default PaperCard;
```

Could someone point out the obvious which I have missed.

Comment: your import is not correct. change typography import to this `import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";`

Working demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/lyq9q46z5z

Comment: I'm afraid this solution doesn't work. Issue is with `CardHeader` import as mentioned below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just the case of incorrect import.

Replace the import of `CardHeader` from

```
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/Card";
```

to

```
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader";
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this!